Getting state list with resource IDs
I want to get the full list of objects managed by terraform and their IDs.
I know that I can run terraform state list to get all the resources in the state.
I also know that I can run terraform state show <resource> to get a detailed information about it, including it's ID.
So naturally I created the following script:
for resource in $(terraform state list); do ID=$(terraform state show $resource | grep -E " id\s*=" | head -n 1 | awk -F " = " '{print $2}'); echo "$resource $ID"; done

Which runs on all the resources from the state list and adds them their ID.
My problem is that for big configurations of 100+ resources this script will take a long time to complete.
Is there a way to speed it up? Or maybe m approach is not the best one and there is a more efficient way to achieve the thing I'm looking for?

Thanks to Paolo I was able to get all the resources in one command.
Alternative solution with grep+awk instead of jq is this:
terraform show | grep -e '^    id ' -e '^# '   | awk '/^# / { gsub(/^# /, "", $0); gsub(/:$/, "", $0); printf "%s ", $0; getline; print $3 }'

You could also develop code to parse the state file directly and extract the values in the map/hash/dictionary. That would probably be significantly faster than executing Terraform multiple times.

I didn't trust this way at first, but after the Paolo helped me to get the result with jq I compared it and saw that it works as well terraform show | grep -e '^    id ' -e '^# '   | awk '/^# / { gsub(/^# /, "", $0); gsub(/:$/, "", $0); printf "%s ", $0; getline; print $3 }'

This should give you the desired output:
$ terraform show -json | jq -r '[try .values.root_module.resources[], try .values.root_module.child_modules[].resources[]][] | [.address, .values.id] | @tsv'


thanks! I had to handle the case were "resources" might not be an array terraform show -json | jq -r '.values[].resources | .[]? | [(.address), (.values.id)] | @tsv'. But unfortunately this returns only a partial result with only the direct resources. And all the resources which are defined from modules are missed

@GlebNebolyubov under which scenario is resources not an array?

I was confused by it too, but noticed that it's a bit different - for output there are values but not resources so a null is returned instead

@GlebNebolyubov I got you. Check the updated answer.

Thanks!! In my case I noticed that some of the modules are nested but this returned the full list: terraform show -json | jq -r '[try .values.root_module.resources[], try .values.root_module.child_modules[]?.resources[], try .values.root_module.child_modules[]?.child_modules[]?.resources[]][] | [.address, .values.id] | @tsv'
